# Does being able to factor semiprimes entail being able to factor any number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, modular-arithmetic, factoring

I'm asking this question with specific reference to Shor's Quantum Factorization Algorithm, which uses the fact that finding a non-trivial square root of $1 \pmod N$ for some integer $N$ yields factors of $N$. The plausibility of this setup (i.e. the fact that we don't have to hope to be overly lucky for this to work) relies on the following claims:

1. Let $x$ be chosen randomly from $0 \leq x < p$ is prime. We know that there exists a generator of $\mathbb{Z}_p$, call it $g$, so that $g^k \pmod p = x$. If $k$ is odd, then $\text{ord}(x)$, defined to be the minimum $r$ such that $x^r \pmod p = 1 \pmod p$, is even. Consequently, the probability that $\text{ord}(x)$ is even for a random $x$ is at least $1/2$.
2. If $N = pq$ for primes $p$ and $q$, then with probability at least $3/8$ the order $r$ of a randomly chosen element $x \in \mathbb{Z}_{pq}$ is even, and furthermore, $x^{r/2} \pmod {pq} \neq \pm 1 \pmod {pq}$. The proof of this is roughly as follows:

> Choosing a random $x$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{pq}$ is equivalent to choosing some $a \in \mathbb{Z}_p$ and $b \in \mathbb{Z}_q$. Namely, given some $a = x \pmod p$ and $b \pmod q$, there is exactly one element in $\mathbb{Z}_{pq}$ satisfying these relations, by the Chinese Remainder Theorem. Letting $r_a = \text{ord}(a)$ (with respect to $\mathbb{Z}_p$) and $r_b = \text{ord}(b)$ (with respect to $\mathbb{Z}_q$), clearly we can see that $r_a, r_b ~|~ r$ (where $r = \text{ord}(x)$ with respect to $\mathbb{Z}_{pq}$). From result one, $r_a$ and $r_b$ are even with probability at least $1/2$, so $r$ will be even with probability at least $3/4$.
>
> In addition, we claim that if $r$ is even, the probability that $x^{r/2} \pmod {pq} = \pm 1$ is at most $1/2$. Since $x^{r} = 1 \pmod {pq}$ if and only if $x^r = 1 \pmod p$ and $x^r = 1 \pmod q$, and these in turn imply that $x^{r/2} = \pm 1 \pmod p$ and $x^{r/2} = \pm 1 \pmod q$. We can form four systems of two equations with these, and they will each have unique solutions $x \in \mathbb{Z}_{pq}$. Two of them are $\pm 1$, and thus the other two will thus be non-trivial. The result then follows.

What I fail to see is how this can extend to factoring numbers in general. What if the number were of the form $p^2 q^3$, or $pqr$ (where $p, q, r$ are prime)? Is it either possible to tweak one of these results and its proof so that we can find a non-trivial square root for any $N$ (not just those which are semiprime)? Or alternatively, is there some simple explanation for why factoring just reduces to factoring a semiprime? Thanks!

**UPDATE:** It appears that the following is true (Theorem 5.3 in Nielsen and Chuang, *Quantum Computation and Quantum Information*):

> Suppose $N$ is odd and has $m$ distinct prime factors. If we choose $x$ uniformly under the constraint $\gcd(x, N) = 1$ and $r$ is the order of $x$ modulo $N$, then
> $$\mathbb{P}(r \text{ is even and } x^{r/2} \neq -1 \pmod N) \geq 1 - 2^{-m}$$

But no proof or proof reference is given. If someone can prove this assertion, that would answer my question as well.

Comment: The Shor-algorithm is based on the order of some base modulo the given number. As far as I understood this gives a nontrivial factor in every case (not just in the case of a semiprime). But I never checked this since I am spectical anyway that the Shore-algorithm would actually work assuming we would have a quantum computer.

Comment: An interesting, but probably open question is whether factoring is easier in the case we know that we have a semiprime. Very likely, the answer is "no".

Comment: @Peter Are you claiming that even if $N$ is not a semiprime, the probability of the order of $x$, call it $r$, is even and $x^{r/2} \pmod N$ is still around $3/8$ (or some other constant)? If this were true then factoring in general would be the same as factoring a semiprime, but the proof of the second lemma I gave above seems to specifically rely on the fact that $N$ is a semiprime.

Comment: I am not sure, maybe I did not read the article very careful. If it actually only works for semiprimes, we could use a modified RSA even if quantum computers occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the proof of this statement in Nielsen and Chuang, *Quantum Information and Quantum Computing*, Appendix 4 (thanks to @DaftWullie on QC Stack Exchange). The claim which I believe is correct is slightly different:

> Suppose $N$ is odd and has $m$ distinct prime factors. If we choose $x$ uniformly under the constraint $\gcd(x, N) = 1$ and $r$ is the order of $x$ modulo $N$, then
> $$\mathbb{P}(r \text{ is even and } x^{r/2} \neq -1 \pmod N) \geq 1 - 2^{1-m}$$

Let $\mathbb{Z}_{N}^*$ be the multiplicative group of integers less than $k$ that are relatively prime to $k$. The proof of the statement relies on the following lemma:

> Let $p$ be an odd prime. If $2^d$ is the largest power dividing $\varphi(p^a) = p^{a-1}(p-1)$, then with probability $1/2$ a randomly chosen element of $\mathbb{Z}_{p^a}^*$ will have order divisible by $2^d$.
>
> Proof: $\mathbb{Z}_{p^a}^*$ is cyclic, so there exists a generator $g$ for it, i.e. every element is expressible as $g^k \pmod {p^a}$ for some $k < \varphi(p^a)$. Suppose $x = g^k \pmod {p^a}$ and the order of $x$ modulo $p^a$ is $r$. Consider two cases. If $r$ is odd, then $g^{kr} \pmod {p^a} = 1$, so $\varphi(p^a)$ divides $kr$ (since the order of $g$ must be $\varphi(p^a)$). Since $k$ is odd, $2^d ~|~ r$. Now if $k$ is even, then
> $$x^{\varphi(p^a) /2} \pmod {p^a} = g^{\varphi(p^a) k/2} \pmod {p^a} = 1^{k / 2} \pmod {p^a}$$
> so it follows that $r$ divides $\varphi(p^a) / 2$ and thus, $2^d \nmid r$. But $k$ is odd with probability exactly half, so we are done. $\square$

From here, we note that if $N = p_1^{a_1} \cdots p_k^{a_k}$, then choosing a random element $x$ from $\mathbb{Z}_N^*$ is equivalent to choosing random elements $x_i$ from $\mathbb{Z}_{p_i^{a_i}}^*$ and mandating that $x = x_i \pmod {p_i^{a_i}}$ for all $i$. Let $r_i$ be the period of $x_i$ modulo $p_i^{a_i}$, and define $d_i$ to be such that $2^{d_i}$ is the largest power of two dividing $r_i$.

Let $r$ be the order of $x$ modulo $N$. The crucial claim, then, is that if $r$ is odd or $x^{r/2} \pmod N = -1$, then the $d_i$ must all be the same. Indeed, we can observe that $r_i \mid r$ for every $i$, because
$$x^r = 1 \pmod N \implies x^r \pmod {p_i} = x_i^r \pmod {p_i} = 1 \pmod {p_i}$$
Now if $r$ is odd, then all the $r_i$ must be odd and thus $d_i = 0$ for all $i$. If $x^{r/2} \pmod N = -1$, then by the Chinese Remainder Theorem we must have $x_i^{r/2} = -1 \pmod {p_i^{a_i}}$ for all $i$. This implies that $r_i$ does not divide $r / 2$, for every $i$. In particular, this means that all the $d_i$ must be the same. If this weren't the case, say $d_j \geq d_k + 1$ for some $j$ and $k$, then since $2^{d_j}$ divides $r$, it would have to follow that $r = z \cdot 2^a \cdot 2^{d_k}$ for some integer $z$ and $a = d_j - d_k \geq 1$. Hence, it would follow that $2^{d_k}$ divides $r / 2$, a contradiction.

From here, we note that the probability that all of the $d_i$ are the same is worst (i.e. largest) when the same number $d$ is such that $2^d$ divides $p_i^{a_i}$ for every $i$. In this case however, the lemma dictates that a randomly chosen element from $\mathbb{Z}_{p_i^{a_i}}^*$ has order divisible by $2^d$ with probability half. Now the orders of $x_i$ modulo $p_i^{a_i}$ are chosen independently from one another, so this probability in the worst case is the probability that all of the orders $r_i$ are equivalent to $r_1$, which is $2^{1-m}$ (recall $m$ is the number of distinct prime factors of $N$). The result then follows. $\square$

In particular, this means that Shor's algorithm as commonly written can be applied to any number, and with constant probability of success, it will return a non-trivial factor of it! The probability of success is worst when $N$ is a semiprime (the lower bound on the probability of success is $1/2$) and tends arbitrarily closer to $1$ as the number of prime factors of $N$ increases.